# import data from website in c# using sql server

Tags: c#

I want to import data by giving the searching option in c#. I am using SQL server database to save this data. Please help me what would I use and how to proceed. I think whether I would use a Google search API or a web crawler. I tried for Google search API but this is not helpful.

Comment: How can other user help you if you do not post any detail about your problem?

Comment: i want to  import data about diseases their symptoms and their doctors

Answer (score 0):

Very little information, you need to make sure that when you are creating posts that you clearly specify what you are attempting to do and what code you already have. You'll find that just asking how to do something isn't received well by the SO community, try and when you fail, we'll help.

Now, I'll give you a nudge in the right direction with what you are trying to do. Read up on how to incorporate SQLDataReaders into your application. Link below:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand